# PHP regex pattern to return N slugs/chunks (separated or split on the "/" char.) as matches from a "friendly" URL?

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex pattern that will return N slugs/chunks (all pieces of the URL, separated or split on the "/" char.) as matches from a "friendly" URL.

The pattern should not include the domain or a leading slash.
Also, the pattern should work with an unknown number of slugs and/or slashes.

For example, some example URLs and desired returned slugs/chunks:

- "" = array()
- "foo/bar/" = array('foo', 'bar')
- "foo/bar/baz" = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
- "foo-bar/baz" = array('foo-bar', 'baz')

Finally, I need to pass this regex pattern preg_match (or similar) and have it return the results via the function's $matches parameter.

For example:

```
<?php preg_match($your_pattern, $friendly_url, $your_pattern_matches); ?>
```

... similar results can be prduced using explode().

This pattern is being used in a much more complex scenario than my little old example; requiring the use/forcing me to use regex patterns via preg_match for the solution. Basically, I'm passing preg_match a pattern of choice, which is why I need a regex pattern as opposed to simply using explode.

Your help is GREATLY appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: I have no idea what slugs/chuncks are. Is your input a complete url? And you want the parts after the domain?

Comment: Input is everything that comes after the first trailing slash, after the domain name.  So given the url http://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz the input would be "foo/bar/baz", and $matches would be set to array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')

Comment: So the input is the complete url and you want everything after the domain?

Comment: the input would be "foo/bar/baz", and would return array('foo', 'bar', 'baz') via $matches in preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches)

Comment: I mean, you can do it in a non-generic way, it's just not pretty. Since you can only get one match, you'll have to chain optional capturing groups like `(?:/([^/]+))?` and rely on all urls to have fewer slugs than the nr of capturing groups you anticipated in your expression. The latter could look like `~^/?([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/([^/]+))?~` which would work with urls of up to five segments (`~` is the expression delimiter).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, check the manual of [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$segments = preg_split('[/]', $uri, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

If you insist on preg_match take a look on this:

```
$uri = '/foo-bar/baz';

preg_match_all('%[^/]+%', $uri, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I'm forced to use preg_match, so this won't get me very far.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) would do the job without having to bother with regexes:

```
$matches = explode('/', $url);
```

Comment: I agree this will work, and does produce the desired results, save for some edge cases.  However, this pattern is being used in a much more complex scenario than my little old example; requiring the use/forcing me to use regex patterns via preg_match for the solution.  Basically, I'm passing preg_match() a pattern of choice, which is why I need a regex pattern as opposed to simply using explode.  Thank you anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I don't think you can do what you want with preg_match.

After reading the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

You can see that preg_match will stop at the first match. You want an array of the matches in a friendly url however this can only be achieved by multiple matches , in order to store the values in an array **OR** by a single match which would capture the whole thing. Both of these cases do not fit you so I am afraid that you would have to use something else than preg_match.

Comment: +1. There is simply no way to do everything you want to do with just `preg_match()`.  @carylson, it sounds like you've painted yourself into a corner.